# Две одинаковые переменные не проходят условие Python

Tags: python, telebot

Две переменные одинаковые, но условие не проходят

```
   while msg != arr[randNum] or msg != arr[randNum+1]:
        print(type(msg), type(arr[randNum]))
        print(msg, arr[randNum])
        print(message.from_user.id, current_player)

        if (msg == arr[randNum] or msg == str(arr[randNum+1])) and message.from_user.id != current_player:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text= f'[{message.from_user.first_name}](tg://user?id={message.from_user.id}) - отгадал слово *{message.text}*',
                             parse_mode='markdown',reply_markup=markup)

            isnot = str(check_user(user_id=message.from_user.id))
            print(isnot)
            if isnot == '(0,)':
                reg_db(user_id=message.from_user.id, answers=1, first_name=message.from_user.first_name)
            else:
                plus_ans(answers=1, user_id=message.from_user.id)
                break
        else:
            return
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы отпечатали `arr[randNum]`, а в условии вы проверяете `arr[randNum+1]`

Comment: А ещё не совсем очевидно, что вы имеете в виду под фразой «условие не проходят» и что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать

Comment: в условии я проверяю сходство сразу с двумя переменными, но это не имеет значение. даже если убрать `arr[randNum+1]` ситуация не меняется

Comment: Тогда проверяйте `print(repr(msg), repr(arr[randNum]))` и убедитесь, что вы нигде не путаете кириллицу и латиницу

Comment: Спасибо! Я решил проблему. Оказалось в конце `arr[randNum]` находилась `\n`, но я не думал, что это решает